# Multiple series in devexpress spline xrgraph

Tags: c#, visual-studio, graph, devexpress

I have set up a DevExpress xrGraph in a report in c#. The series data is bound to an object, but each series needs to come from a separate occurrence of the object... Not explaining well but to illustrate:

**What I have so far**

```
public class Data {
   public List<TestItem> Tests {get; set;}
}

public class TestItem {
   public string TestNumber {get; set;}
   public Graph GraphData {get; set;}
}

public class Graph {
   public List<Tuple<string, decimal, decimal>> Samples {get; set;}
}
```

then...

```
var test1Info = new TestItem();
test1Info.TestNumber = "Test 1";
test1Info.GraphData.Samples = new List<Tuple<string, decimal, decimal>>
    {
    new Tuple<string, decimal, decimal>("Test 1", 0, 0),
    new Tuple<string, decimal, decimal>("Test 1", 0.01M, 0.07M),
    new Tuple<string, decimal, decimal>("Test 1", 0.02M, 0.14M),
    new Tuple<string, decimal, decimal>("Test 1", 0.03M, 0.20M),
    new Tuple<string, decimal, decimal>("Test 1", 0.04M, 0.26M),
    new Tuple<string, decimal, decimal>("Test 1", 0.05M, 0.31M)
    };

report.TestData.Add(test1Info);

var test2Info = new TestItem();
test2Info.TestNumber = "Test 2";
test2Info.VolumeTimeInfo.Samples = new List<Tuple<string, decimal, decimal>>
{
    new Tuple<string, decimal, decimal>("Test 2", 0, 0),
    new Tuple<string, decimal, decimal>("Test 2", 0.01M, 0.07M),
    new Tuple<string, decimal, decimal>("Test 2", 0.02M, 0.21M),
    new Tuple<string, decimal, decimal>("Test 2", 0.03M, 0.55M),
    new Tuple<string, decimal, decimal>("Test 2", 0.04M, 0.90M),
    new Tuple<string, decimal, decimal>("Test 2", 0.05M, 1.66M),
    new Tuple<string, decimal, decimal>("Test 2", 0.06M, 1.99M),
    new Tuple<string, decimal, decimal>("Test 2", 0.07M, 2.15M)
}

report.TestData.Add(test2Info);
```

In my graph properties I have set

`SeriesDataMember` to `TestData.Tests.Samples.Item1`

and in `SeriesTemplate`:

`ArgumentDataMember` to `TestData.Tests.Samples.Item2`

In `ValueDataMambers` I've set `Value` to `TestData.Tests.Samples.Item3`

**The problem:**

However, the graph only draws one curve, i.e. Test 1. How can I get it to look at the rest of the occurrences of `Tests`? Now if I move the Test 2 data to test1Info (i.e. the first occurrence of `Tests`, then the will display both of them fine. However I don't want to do this. For one thing, the classes are a lot more complex than the code I've given above, and to do this - to put all the tests in together would go against the existing class structure. But also, I believe having "Test 1", etc. in each sample is a bit cumbersome (there are actually thousands of them), and I'd rather take the label from the `TestNumber` property.

But at the moment if I set the `SeriesDataMember` to `TestData.Tests.TestNumber`, now I can see both tests in the Legend, but only a single dot (the first point from the Samples of the first test) is drawn on the graph!

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this by adding a property to the `Data` class that returns the data in the format the dev express chart seems to need it. Feels like a bit of a workaround and I'm not sure it's any more efficient, so I'd still like to know is there a correct way of doing what I am trying to do.

First of all I removed the `string` from the `Samples` tuple. Then...

```
public class Data {

    public List<TestItem> Tests {get; set;}

    public List<Tuple<string, decimal, decimal>>  AllGraphSamples
    {
        get
        {
            var allGraphData = new List<Tuple<string, decimal, decimal>>();

            foreach (var test in Tests)
            {
                var graphData = test.GraphData.Samples.Select(
                    s => new Tuple<string, decimal, decimal>
                             (
                             string.Format("Test {0}", test.TestNumber),
                             s.Item1,
                             s.Item2
                             )).ToList();

                allGraphData.AddRange(graphData);
            }

            return allGraphData;
        }
    }
```

My graph is now pointed at the same members of this property rather than the `GraphData.Samples` one.